# Validación en javascript de un formulario html no reconoce todas las condiciones

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Yo construí un programa para validar un formulario de html en javascript, lo único que valida son las regex (del campo de nombre de usuario) y las demás condiciones no las lee. Además que solo lee el primer campo que es el nombre, y los demás campos los ignora, en este caso ¿que podría hacer? Intenté crear una función para cada campo, pero tampoco funcionó. Esto es lo que me sale en el navegador al mandar el formulario.

[image: Este es el formulario creado]

No sé si puedo copiar todo el codigo de javascript aquí, así que copiaré solo el primer fragmento:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  href='style.css'>
    <script src='script.js' defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h2>Registrese al curso</h2>
    </div>
<div class="contenedorprincipal">
    <div class="contenedortexto">
        <p>
            Bienvenido al formulario de registro, gracias por elegir nuestra plataforma
            de cursos, ¡mejore su aprendizaje hoy!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorform">
        <div class="direcciontexto">
            <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkFormulario()" name="formularioregistro" id="formularioregistro">
                <div class="Camponombre">
                    <label for="nombre" >Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="Campoemail">
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="Campocontraseña">
                    <label for="contraseña" >Contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contraseña" id="contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="Campocontraseñados">
                    <label for="contraseñados" >Repita su contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contraseñados" id="contraseñados">
                </div>
                <div class="Camponumero">
                    <label for="numerotlf" class="Camponumero">Número telefonico:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="numerotlf" id="numerotlf">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="botonenviar" name="envio" id="envio">Enviar</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("nombre");
const emailUsuario = document.getElementById("email");
const contraseñaUsuario = document.getElementById("contraseña");
const contraseñaUsuarioDos = document.getElementById("contraseñados");
const telefonoUsuario = document.getElementById("numerotlf");
const formularioRegistro = document.getElementById("formularioregistro").addEventListener('submit', checkFormulario)

function checkFormulario() {
        
        if(nombreUsuario === "" || nombreUsuario === null || nombreUsuario.lenght === 0) {
        alert("Error: debe llenar este campo");
        nombreUsuario.focus();
        return false; 
        }

        else if(nombreUsuario.lenght <= 3 || nombreUsuario.lenght >= 20) {
        alert("Error: el nombre usuario debe tener entre 4 y 19 caracteres");
        nombreUsuario.focus();
        return false;
        }

        else if ( !(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nombreUsuario)) ) {
        alert("Error: solo debe introducir valores alfanumericos") 
        nombreUsuario.focus();
        return false;
        
        } //solo está validando este bloque de código, lo demás lo ignora
    
        
        if(emailUsuario === "" || emailUsuario === null || emailUsuario.lenght === 0) {
            alert("Error: debe llenar este campo");
            emailUsuario.focus();
            return false;
        }

        else if( !(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(emailUsuario)) ) {
            alert("Error: debe ingresar un correo valido");
            emailUsuario.focus();
            return false;
        }

} return true
```

Esa era la función javascript que creé, espero se entienda bien.

Comment: sin entrar mucho a detalles, como por cada if haces un `return false;` se sale de la función y ya no hace nada más, quieres que valide todo y después marque error?

Comment: Si, quiero que valide cada campo y que al validar muestre un ```alert``` con el error y haga ```focus()``` en ese campo donde faltó ingresar los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes eliminar todos esos `return false;` porque no permite continuar con las siguientes validaciones. Una opción es crear un arreglo para guardar los errores y una variable adicional para saber qué campo es el que debe recibir el foco.

Otro cambio es que se quitó el `onsubmit="checkFormulario()"`, dejando solo la función agregada por `.addEventListener()` y recibiendo el evento como parámetro.

Finalmente, un error importante, estás comparando campos y no sus valores, debes agregar la propiedad `.value`.

```js
const nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("nombre");
const emailUsuario = document.getElementById("email");
const contraseñaUsuario = document.getElementById("contraseña");
const contraseñaUsuarioDos = document.getElementById("contraseñados");
const telefonoUsuario = document.getElementById("numerotlf");
document.getElementById("formularioregistro").addEventListener('submit', checkFormulario)

// El evento se recibe como parámetro, para poder cancelarlo si es necesario
function checkFormulario(e) {
        // Crea un arreglo para los mensajes de error
        let errors = [];
        // También una variable para poner foco al primer campo que tenga error
        let input = false;
        
        // Considerar cualquier valor tipo falsy (null, cadena vacía, etc.)
        if(!nombreUsuario.value) {
            errors.push("Usuario: Debe llenar este campo");
            input = nombreUsuario;
        } else if(nombreUsuario.value.length <= 3 || nombreUsuario.value.length >= 20) {
            errors.push("Usuario: El nombre usuario debe tener entre 4 y 19 caracteres");
            input = nombreUsuario;
        } else if ( !(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nombreUsuario.value)) ) {
            errors.push("Usuario: Solo debe introducir valores alfanuméricos") 
            input = nombreUsuario;
        }
        if(!emailUsuario.value) {
            errors.push("Correo: Debe llenar este campo");
            // Solo si no hay error en campo previo
            if(!input) {
                input = emailUsuario;
            }
        } else if( !(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(emailUsuario.value)) ) {
            errors.push("Correo: Debe ingresar un correo válido");
            if(!input) {
                input = emailUsuario;
            }
        }
        // ¿Hay errores?
        if(errors.length > 0) {
            // Cancelar envío, usando el evento
            e.preventDefault();
            // Mostrar mensaje de error, mostrar con saltos de línea \n
            alert('Errores en formulario, por favor corrija:\n' + errors.join('\n'));
            // Poner foco en el primer campo con error
            input.focus();
        }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'  href='style.css'>
    <script src='script.js' defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h2>Registrese al curso</h2>
    </div>
<div class="contenedorprincipal">
    <div class="contenedortexto">
        <p>
            Bienvenido al formulario de registro, gracias por elegir nuestra plataforma
            de cursos, ¡mejore su aprendizaje hoy!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorform">
        <div class="direcciontexto">
            <form action="" method="POST" name="formularioregistro" id="formularioregistro">
                <div class="Camponombre">
                    <label for="nombre" >Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
                </div>
                <div class="Campoemail">
                    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="Campocontraseña">
                    <label for="contraseña" >Contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contraseña" id="contraseña">
                </div>
                <div class="Campocontraseñados">
                    <label for="contraseñados" >Repita su contraseña:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contraseñados" id="contraseñados">
                </div>
                <div class="Camponumero">
                    <label for="numerotlf" class="Camponumero">Número telefonico:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="numerotlf" id="numerotlf">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="botonenviar" name="envio" id="envio">Enviar</button>
            </form>
            </div>
            
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, acabo de correrlo, y es buen metodo, los mensajes de error salen 1 por 1

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente hay 2 formas de hacerlo. la más fácil y sin `Javascript`, es que uses el mismo `html` para que valide tus campos:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkFormulario()" name="formularioregistro"
                    id="formularioregistro">
                    <div class="Camponombre">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Campoemail">
                        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="Campocontraseña">
                        <label for="contraseña">Contraseña:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="contraseña" id="contraseña" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Campocontraseñados">
                        <label for="contraseñados">Repita su contraseña:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="contraseñados" id="contraseñados" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Camponumero">
                        <label for="numerotlf" class="Camponumero">Número telefonico:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="numerotlf" id="numerotlf" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="botonenviar" name="envio" id="envio">Enviar</button>
                </form>
```

¿que agregué?

- `Required`: hace que un `input` sea requerido que se llene para enviar el formulario.
- `Input type="email"`: hace que el `input` requiera el formato de correo para que sea válido
- `Input type="password"`: hace que el campo no muestre lo que escribes.

De esta manera, **No necesitarías usar `Javascript`.**
Ahora, si quieres usar `Javascript`, hay que modificar un poco tu función:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        const nombreUsuario = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        const emailUsuario = document.getElementById("email").value;
        const contraseñaUsuario = document.getElementById("contraseña").value;
        const contraseñaUsuarioDos = document.getElementById("contraseñados").value;
        const telefonoUsuario = document.getElementById("numerotlf").value;
        const formularioRegistro = document.getElementById("formularioregistro").addEventListener('submit', checkFormulario)

        function checkFormulario() {
            //creamos una variable de texto que tendrá el error, y un booleano que guarde si algo está mal
            let TextoError="Se encontraron los siguientes errores:\n";
            let correcto=true;
            //debemos validar uno por uno, así que los "else" no son correctos aquí.
            //con un if que falle, correcto pasará a ser false, y guardamos el error en texto
            if (nombreUsuario === "" || nombreUsuario === null || nombreUsuario.length === 0) {
                TextoError+="Nombre de usuario: debe llenar este campo\n";
                correcto=false;
            }
            //como ya no hay else, entra a validar todo.
            if (nombreUsuario.length <= 3 || nombreUsuario.length>= 20) {
                TextoError+="Nombre de usuario: el nombre usuario debe tener entre 4 y 19 caracteres\n";
                correcto = false;
            }

            if (!(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nombreUsuario))) {
                TextoError+="Error: solo debe introducir valores alfanumericos\n";
                correcto = false;

            } 


            if (emailUsuario === "" || emailUsuario === null || emailUsuario.length === 0) {
                TextoError+="Error: debe llenar este campo\n";
                correcto=false;
            }

            if (!(/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(emailUsuario))) {
                TextoError+="Error: debe ingresar un correo valido\n";
                correcto = false;
            }
            //finalmente, validamos como quedó el booleano "correcto":
            //si no hubo errores, "correcto" es true y se devuelve nada más.
            if(correcto){
                return correcto;
            }
            //si "correcto" es false, devolvemos el texto del error y false.
            else{
                alert(TextoError);
                return correcto;
            }
        } 
    </script>
```

Te explico en comentarios cuál fue el cambio, pero en pocas palabras, hago que ahora en `Javascript` entre a todos los `if` y al final te muestre cual es el problema.

Espero mi respuesta te sirva, ¡Saludos!:D

Comment: Solo podrías editar la palabra "lenght" por "length" amigo :)

Comment: no había notado eso en el código del OP, editando

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, voy a probarlo y ver si funciona, esperemos que si, esto también se podría aplicar si quisiera validar contraseña y número telefonico? Tambíen quería crear una validación para confirmar la contraseña (es decir escribo primero la contraseña y en otro campo la repito para confirmar) asumo que para hacer eso simplemente podría usar el operador ```!==```?

Comment: @MiguelDavid para validar el número de teléfono, podrías usar `input type="number"` sí y sólo sí, en tu formulario sólo irán números, nada de guiones medios, o caracteres no numéricos. Respecto a la contraseña, debe ser una validación en javascript, y el operador sería `!=`. ¡Saludos! :D